# HElp! Can i still reach master level?

Tags: rating

I started playing chess when i was 13,  year 2009. After a year and a half i reached 1850 peek ncfp(philppines) rating, i was 14 turning 15 that time. Due to personal reasons, I stopped playing chess when i was 16. Leaving my ncfp rating 1805. Now im turning 21. I started playing again. I stopped for nearly 5 years without playing. And just got back my interest in the game recently. The question is can i stil be at leastt ba national master or is it too late. I practiced almost everyday again and have a 1860 rating in chess.com. is it still possible for me to get into master level?? Because since i started playing. I dreamed to be a master. Its a broken dream for me that i want to continue. I have a hard time playing because i think that im left out with my batchmates from chess . Some of them are masters already. Thankss!

Comment: First thing: don't take advice from anyone here that is not at least a Candidate Master because they probably don't know what it takes and certainly has not walked the path. With that, I will be silent as I am only a Cat A player. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with enough study and practice, it's possible to become a master at any age. There's even a book titled ["Chess Master at any Age"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0938650580), written by a player who became a master at the age of 50.

Comment: I think im stronger when i was young. But im having a hard time getting it back. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not dead, you still have time.

> I think im stronger when i was young. But im having a hard time getting it back. What should i do?

Take shortcuts, cheat, drink at tournaments...

Come on, man. Take a deep breath and realize that there's nothing to be anxious about. It's going to happen as fast as it's going to happen. But you can get started on that process by opening a chess book, reading it, and applying what you learned over-the-board (and by yourself at home, playing against yourself).

Any chess book that you learn even just one thing from was useful. Here's my list:

1. *100 Endgames You Must Know* by Jesus De La Villa
2. *Re-assess Your Chess* by Jeremy Silman
3. *Art of Attack* by Vladimir Vukovic

Those three are more than enough to get you started.